# How to use Reactive form for array of objects?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need a reactive form for this output

```
sites: Array(2)
0: {Id: 218, siteId: 1}
1: {Id: 218, siteId: 9}
length: 2
```

I tried with

.service file

```
  resetForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      sites: this.fb.array([this.createSites()]),
    });
  }
  createSites(){
    return this.fb.group({
      Id:['',Validators.required],
      siteId:['',Validators.required],
    })
  }
```

.ts file

```
  get Form() {
    return this.Service.form;
  }
  get formControl() {
    return this.Form.controls;
  }
  get siteControls() {
   return (this.Form.get('sites') as FormArray).controls; 
 }
```

.html file

```
 <div class="col-md-3 select-site-btn">
     <div formArrayName="sites" 
         *ngFor="let site of siteControls; 
          let siteIndex = index">
              <div [formGroupName]="siteIndex">
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label" for="siteId">Site</label>
                        <nb-select multiple fullWidth placeholder="Select site"
                        formControlName="siteId">
                            <nb-option *ngFor = "let site of sites" [value]="site.id" > {{site.name}} </nb-option>
                        </nb-select>
                  </div>
              </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**BUT this give output like this,**

```
sites: Array(1)
0:{Id: 218, siteId: [9, 1, 2]}
```

BUT I NEED like this format

```
sites: Array(2)
0: {Id: 218, siteId: 1}
1: {Id: 218, siteId: 9}
length: 2
```

What is issue in my code? Could anyone help me to find the issue?

Comment: you has create a FormArray with only one element, you should use `sites: this.fb.array([this.createSites(),this.createSites()])`,

Comment: @Eliseo This gives 2 drop-down select buttons. This way is not suitable

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building it like this:

```
sites: any[] = [
  { Id: 218, siteId: 1 },
  { Id: 218, siteId: 9 }
]

resetForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    sites: new FormArray([]),
  });
  createSites(this.form);
  console.log(this.form.get('sites');
} 
 
createSites(form: FormGroup){
  this.sites.forEach(site => {
    form.push(
      this.fb.group({ Id: site.Id, siteId: site.siteId })
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: in general I prefer use a function that return the formGroup and iterate when you create the form: `this.form = this.fb.group({sites: new FormArray(this.sites.map(site=>createSites(site)),});` and `createSites(data:any=null){data=data || {Id:0,siteId:''};return this.fb.group(site)}`. This allow add a new "site" using `(this.Form.get('sites') as FormArray).push(this.createSite())`